# Vectorizing a function with two inputs

Tags: julia, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following functions:

```
function f(x)
    z1 = 3*x
    z2 = x^2
    return z1,z2
end

function g(x,y)
    z = 2*x + 3*y*im
    return z
end
```

My goal, is to have one vector input as `x` to a function `f(x)`, then take the result of the function `g(x,y)` and get a single vector output.

When I try to do the following:

```
x̂ = collect(range(0,10,step=0.01))
g.(f.(x̂))
```

I get the error:

> MethodError: no method matching g(::Tuple{Float64, Float64})

I'm not sure exactly how to make this case work, I guess the fact that the function `f` returns two values causes the issue, however, it should technically work because the function `g` takes two inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `g(x,y)` is defined for two arguments but `f(x)` outputs `Tuple`s, what you want is to `Splat` the function `g` before feeding the tuples into it. Splatting means, given a function, return a new function that takes one argument and splats its argument into the original function.

This is achieved by `Base.splat` or simply `Splat` in the upcoming Julia releases.

```
function f(x)
    z1 = 3*x
    z2 = x^2
    return z1,z2
end

function g(x,y)
    z = 2*x + 3*y*im
    return z
end

x̂ = range(0,10,step=0.01)
Base.splat(g).(f.(x̂))

# Or Julia 1.9
Splat(g).(f.(x̂))
```